# On change of select get the Html of mutiple tr Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On change of type_id i want to get the complete html of tr whose id is change and values .After that i want to set the selected value in the type_id that is not selected in the above html.Means if One is selected then in the html i have to set Two selected .How can we do this,

**HTML**

```
<tr id ="change">
                    <td style="font-size:12px">Type</td>
                    <td colspan="7">
                        <select name="type" id="type_id"><option value="">Select Type</option><option value="O">One</option><option value="R">Two</option></select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display: table-row;" class="is_rows_hidden" id ="values">
                    <td style="font-size:12px">Percentage</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="percentageid" name="percentage" value="" type="text">
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size:12px">On</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="markup" id="markup"><option value="BF">BF</option><option value="YY">YT</option><option value="TF">TF</option></select>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size:12px">Amount </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="amount_id" name="amount" value="" type="text">
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size:12px">ApplyOn</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="apply_on" id="apply_on" class="select-box" style="width:127px;">
                        <option value="PP">PP</option><option value="PB">PB</option><option value="PX">PX</option></select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I have tried this by using this

```
var html = $('tr.change td:gt(1)').map(function(){
              return this.outerHTML;
           }).get().join('');
```

But this is not working for me 
Main issue in after getting the html in the variable how can we do the changes in the html

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/79/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('change', '#type_id', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var html = $(this).parents('#change:first').html();
    var o = $('#type_id').find('option').filter(function() {    
        return (($(this).attr('value') != val)&&($(this).attr('value'))); 
    });
    $(this).val(o.attr('value'));
    console.log(html,o);
});
});
```